# I have a problem with pytest execution, I install the pytest but it doesnot show it's version neither it works

Tags: python, pip, pytest

```
C:\Users\sbhandari>python --version
Python 3.9.1
```

```
C:\Users\sbhandari>pip install pytest


Collecting pytest
  Using cached pytest-6.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (279 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: toml in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pytest) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<1.0.0a1,>=0.12 in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pytest) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: iniconfig in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pytest) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.8.2 in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pytest) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pytest) (20.8)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pytest) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: atomicwrites>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pytest) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pytest) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\sbhandari\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from packaging->pytest) (2.4.7)
Installing collected packages: pytest
  WARNING: The scripts py.test.exe and pytest.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\sbhandari\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pytest-6.2.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\sbhandari\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

```
C:\Users\sbhandari>pytest
'pytest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You can try  ` python -m pytest `  or add the scripts folder of the installed python into your environment variable path.

Comment: It does not work instead it says some system error

Comment: If you check the output, you will see the reason: `WARNING: The scripts py.test.exe and pytest.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\sbhandari\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

it worked on my computer,i think its not working on your computer because you haven't added it to system variables(PATH),[here's how you can do so](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

pytest and other scripts are mostly present in a directory(in python folder) named 'Scripts'.maybe yours is somewhere else and if so then type pytest.exe in start menu and copy the file location and add it to system variables.if this doesnt work try re-installing pytest or python.

**Edit**:if you check the output pip is telling you that `WARNING: The scripts py.test.exe and pytest.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\sbhandari\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`just add the directory above on your path and it should solve your problem